# Update text in a ListView

Tags: java, javafx

I am trying update the text of an `index` in my `ListView` when text is typed into a `TextField`, but I don't know how to access the item to update the text. I know the `index` of the item, but I just cant seem to figure out how to update the text..

```
@FXML
ListView connections;

public ObservableList names = FXCollections.observableArrayList();

@FXML
public void onInputChanged(KeyEvent event){
    TextField fld = (TextField) event.getTarget();
    if(fld.getId().equals("txtName") && index > -1){

    }
}
```

Comment: Can you explain more clearly what you mean? What do you mean by the "text of an `index`" (when `index` appears to be an `int`)? What is the relationship between the `ListView`, `ObservableList`, and the `TextField`? It would also help if you properly type the `ListView` and `ObservableList` instead of using raw types (i.e. `ListView<...> connections ;` (replace the `...` with the actual type of thing you are displaying).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
names.set(index, fld.getText());
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to use JavaFX Properties i.e. "SimpleStringProperty" to actually change the String in "names".

This link does explain it pretty accurately:
https://gist.github.com/andytill/3116827

Hope it helps.